# Nail hole plug not repairable?

Tags: tires

I had a plug put inside a nail hole only to have another flat afterwards. The flat tire was rolled on for about 100 meters before it was refilled with air.

1. Is it worth redoing the plug?
2. Could this be sign of another problem?
3. Could rolling 100 m on a flat tire have damaged the tire?

Comment: Where I'm from, plugs are like $0.50. Is it "worth" redoing?  Well, it's basically free to try, but if it failed once, it will probably fail again.  If the tire is not damaged from rolling on it, I would recommend looking for a place to do **patch** on the inside of the tire.  They may say that the tire is too damaged to be patched and you would need to get a new one.

Comment: Is it a separate nail that caused your 2nd puncture or did your plug fail?

Comment: I will check and get back... if i find only 1 nail i will do a water test to see if bubbles emanate from the plug.

Comment: So I checked out the tire again under water - the plug is holding but air is coming out from the rim of my mag - does that mean the tire is finished? There is no 2nd nail so we can rule that out...

Comment: No, but it does mean the correct next step is getting a tire shop (or your mechanic) to fix it. They'll have to re-seal it to the rim.

Comment: tnx:) Already have my winter tires on so i can take my time to get it fixed..

Answer (score 1):

> Is it worth redoing the plug?

Maybe.

> Could this be sign of another problem?

Yes.

> Could rolling 100 m on a flat tire have damaged the tire?

Rolling around on a flat tire is not great for the bead to wheel connection.  It's almost certainly not seating properly.  At this point, I would assume that a plug won't be a long term fix, especially since you had a recurring flat even before you drove on it for a bit.